# SciKit-Learn: Trouble Using train_test_split

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm using Pandas and SciKit-Learn to do some basic data cleaning and then ML.  I have a `words_df` DataFrame that's 983 rows x 33,600 columns.  The columns are mostly from running TFIDF as below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
corpus = result_df['_text'].tolist()
count_vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english')
dtm = count_vect.fit_transform(corpus)
word_counts = dtm.toarray()
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(word_counts)
words_df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf.todense(), columns=count_vect.get_feature_names())
```

I extract an X and a Y (input instances and their target values, in my case page views).  X is a DataFrame and Y is a Series (I just use `words_df['_pageviews']`).

I then run:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got estimator      _title
```

Is this because one of my columns is called `_title`?  I'm not sure what else could be causing this error.

Thanks!

Comment: First, you can use TfidfVectorizer which combines both CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer. Second, please post the full stack trace of error, along with how you define X and y. X as dataframe is allowed so I see no reason of that not working or you using `X.as_matrix()` to make it work.

Comment: Also, having '_title' as column names should not be a problem. And please describe your problem in detail. You post code about `word_counts`, `tfidf`, `words_df`  etc, but in `train_test_split` passing X and y. What are these X and y and from where they came?

Comment: The error you specified can only come if the dataframe has a column named `fit` which may be the case when you use the `count_vect.get_feature_names()`

Comment: `X.as_matrix()` will work because that doesnot take column names into consideration. As a workaround use `words_df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf.todense())`, then split the arrays. And then use `X_train.columns = count_vect.get_feature_names()` and `X_test.columns = count_vect.get_feature_names()`

Comment: So is the problem solved?